# (Edited) Let $f:R\to R^+$ a continuous function where $f(x)f(-x)=1$ for every $x \in R$. Is $f$ necessarily the exponential?

Tags: exponential-function

Additionally, we suppose $f'(x)\neq 0$ in any point, so it is not constant at any interval.

Comment: Well, your first implication isn't strictly true.  the function $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ satisfies the functional equation.  Beyond that...I'm not sure what you are asking.  There are exotic functions that satisfy the functional equation, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423492/overview-of-basic-facts-about-cauchy-functional-equation)  Did you at least want to assume continuity?

Comment: You're wright, but if $f(x)\neq0$, then, if $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$, so $f(x)f(0)=f(x+0)=f(x)$, so $f(0)=1$, then $f(x)f(-x)=f(0)=1$, so the first implication is true. I just want to know if the inverse is true, so if $f(x)f(-x)=f(0)=1$ then  $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$. The question you pointed out is about $f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$, which is not the case. And yes, we assume continuity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take any function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$ with $f(0)=1$ that doesn't take the value $0$, and define $f$ on $(-\infty, 0)$ by $f(x) = 1/f(-x)$.

Comment: You could also do the same thing if $f(0) = -1$ of course...

Comment: But how this proves the question?

Comment: @QuantumBrachistochrone The question, as I understand it, is whether the equation $f(x) f(-x) = 1$ implies $f(x) f(y) = f(x+y)$ (or maybe that $f(x) = \exp(c x)$ for some $c$).  This shows that the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

We have this result if $f$ is continuous: [Prove if $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ then $f(x)=a^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2177866/prove-if-fxy-fxfy-then-fx-ax). For $f$ not necessarily continuous, consider for example:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in \mathbb Q \\ -1 & x \not \in \mathbb Q\end{cases}$$

since $x$ is rational iff $-x$ is.

Comment: This does not answer the question because the assumption is $f(x)f(-x)=1$, not $f(x)f(y)=f(x+y)$, the second implies the first, obviously, but the question is in fact if the first implies the second.

Comment: Well for this function $f(\sqrt 2 + \sqrt 2) = -1$ while $f(\sqrt 2)f(\sqrt 2) = 1$, yet $f(x)f(-x) = 1$ for all $x$... The question title and the body ask two different things

Comment: If $f$ is continuous and satisfies $f(x+y) = f(x) f(y)$, then $f$ is an exponential.  But $f$ can be continuous and satisfy $f(x) f(-x) = 1$ and not be an exponential: see my answer.

Comment: @RobertIsrael sure, was just not very clear what the OP was asking and continuity was thrown in after I posted the answer